# Dynamically and correctly adding the same type of row for a datatable with a dynamic column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

My datatable allows the user to add row using the datatable API.

```
$('#table_add').on( 'click', function () {
    table.row.add( [
        "<textarea id=\"mp\" name=\"c1\"></textarea>",
        "<input type=\"number\" id=\"dis\" name=\"col2\">",
        "<input type=\"number\" id=\"mrc\" name=\"col3\">",
        "<input type=\"number\" id=\"mdp\" name=\"col4\">",
    ] ).draw(false);
    mpsum++
} );
```

Columns can be added as well.

```
function AddColumn(){
    $('#table tr').append($("<td>"));
    $('#table thead tr>td:last').append($("<textarea id=\"m\" name=\"addedHeader\"></textarea>"));
    $('#mptable tbody tr').each(function(){
        mpsum++;
        $(this).children('td:last').append($("<input type=\"number\" id=\"mdp\" name=\"addedRows\">"))});
}
```

This is how my datatables look before adding anything.

[image: Before adding anything]

---

The user can add new rows correctly if he adds new rows before adding new columns.

[image: Add Rows before Columns]
*Add Rows before Columns*

---

However, My datatable is unable to add new rows correctly into the new columns if the user adds new column before he add new rows.

[image: Add Columns before Rows]
*Add Columns before Rows*

---

Is there anything I could do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** add columns dynamically. At all. It *seems* to work, but only because you are dealing with the DOM through jQuery. As soon as you are trying to do anything with dataTables API it will fail. The markup is no longer consistent with the underlying dataTables "cache" or internal structure. You *must* regenerate the dataTable in order to successfully adding columns. Here is a scheme for doing that :

```
//Your table must have destroy: true
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  //other options goes here
  destroy: true
})  

//in AddColumn, destroy() the table, then add new DOM nodes properly
//table = $('#example').DataTable({}) will recreate the dataTable
//WITH the old settings
function AddColumn() {
  table.destroy();
  $('#example thead tr').append('<th>New</th>');
  $('#example tbody tr').each(function(i, tr) {
    $(tr).append('<td>'+i+'</td>');
  })
  table = $('#example').DataTable({})
}
```

After this, you can add new rows to the table. Of course you should insert whatever you want to the new `<th>` and new `<td>`'s. Was confused by you referring to two different tables :) See working demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qmh399ap/**

Comment: Congrats with the golden `datatables` badge!